# Extract the content of a specific folder from a zip archive in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have a zip archive whose internal structure looks like this:

```
file.zip
  |
   --- foo/
  |
   --- bar/
        |
         --- file1.txt
        |
         --- dir/
              |
               --- file2.txt
```

and I would like to extract the content of `bar` to an output directory using python3, getting something that looks like so:

```
output-dir/
    |
     --- file1.txt
    |
     --- dir/
          |
           --- file2.txt
```

However, when I run the code below both `bar` and it's content is being extracted to `output-dir`

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('path/to/file.zip')

for archive_item in archive.namelist():
    if archive_item.startswith('bar/'):
        archive.extract(archive_item, 'path/to/output-dir')
```

How can I tackle this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Not really a solution, but a way of circumventing the problem: extract to `path/to`, so you get `path/to/bar`, then rename `path/to/bar` to `path/to/output-dir`.

Comment: change `archive_item.startswith('file/bar/')` it will give bar directory content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `ZipFile.extract`, use `ZipFile.open`, `open` and `shutil.copyfileobj` in order to put the file *exactly* where you want it to be, using path manipulation to create the output path you need.

```py
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('path/to/file.zip')
PREFIX = 'bar/'
out = pathlib.Path('path/to/output-dir')
for archive_item in archive.namelist():
    if archive_item.startswith(PREFIX):
        # strip out the leading prefix then join to `out`, note that you 
        # may want to add some securing against path traversal if the zip
        # file comes from an untrusted source
        destpath = out.joinpath(archive_item[len(PREFIX):])
        # make sure destination directory exists otherwise `open` will fail
        os.makedirs(destpath.parent, exist_ok=True)
        with archive.open(archive_item) as source,
             open(destpath, 'wb') as dest:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, dest)
```

something like that.

Comment: I suggest changing `4` to `len('bar/')` to make it easier to modify.